# Type failure when using 'left' Lens from fclabels

Tags: haskell, lenses

I've made a minimal example for testing out fclabels. Using a lens to retrieve a 'right' value from an Either value. Why does this fail? Have I missed including something?

```
module Label where
import Data.Label
import Data.Label.Base

test = get right (Right "test")

{- Will fail with this message:
Label.hs:5:12:
    No instance for (Control.Arrow.ArrowZero Data.Label.Point.Total)
      arising from a use of `right'
    Possible fix:
      add an instance declaration for
      (Control.Arrow.ArrowZero Data.Label.Point.Total)
    In the first argument of `get', namely `right'
    In the expression: get right (Right "test")
    In an equation for `test': test = get right (Right "test")
Failed, modules loaded: none.

-- Tested with fclabels-2.0.2
-}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is rather obscure, but it becomes clearer when we look at the types and documentation of [`get`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels-2.0.2/docs/Data-Label.html#v:get) and [`right`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels-2.0.2/docs/Data-Label-Base.html#v:right):

```
get :: (f :-> a) -> f -> a
type :-> f o = Lens Total f o

right :: (ArrowZero arr, ArrowApply arr, ArrowChoice arr)
      => Lens arr (Either a b -> Either a o) (b -> o)

-- Lens pointing to the right value in an Either. (Partial and polymorphic)
```

Essentially the `get` you're using is only for *total* lenses, but `right` isn't a total lens as it wouldn't work if the value was a `Left`. The error is saying that a partial lens requires the carrier type to be an `ArrowZero`, but that total lenses can't do that.

If you experiment in `ghci`, you get this error just from calling `get right`, without any arguments.

If you change the import of `Data.Label` to [`Data.Label.Partial`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels-2.0.2/docs/Data-Label-Partial.html), then your code works. `test` ends up with the type `Maybe String`.